# Is it possible to do a groupby on the result of a groupby?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I don't think I need to share the entire dataframe, but basically, this is the line of code in question (with pandas already imported, of course)

```
divstack = df[df['Competitor']=='Emma Slabach'].groupby(['Division','Stack'])['Time'].min()
```

The output is :

```
>>> divstack
Division  Stack 
6U F      3/3/03     2.66
          3/6/03     4.81
          Cycle     13.89
7-8 F     3/3/03     2.41
          3/6/03     2.68
          Cycle      7.71
9-10 F    3/3/03     2.13
          3/6/03     2.75
          Cycle      6.94
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

I already grabbed Emma's fastest time is `2.13`, thanks to this line of code:

`emma = df[df['Competitor']=='Emma Slabach'].groupby(['Competitor'])['Time'].min()`

and the output is:

```
>>> emma
Competitor
Emma Slabach    2.13 
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

But how would I go about modifying the first line of code from earlier to specifically obtain the `Division` and `Stack` (along with `Time`) of when her fastest time occurred? (Division 9-10F and Stack 3/3/03).

I don't think a function is necessary, but is there a way I can perform another groupby on top of that first groupby output (`divstack`) I got, to further "minimize" and get her fastest time?
Or could I input `emma` somewhere in `divstack` to obtain which division/stack that time occurs?

I need to store the division, stack, and time into `divstack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `divstack`, you can retrieve the full MultiIndex entry with `.loc` and `min()`:

```
divstack.loc[divstack.eq(divstack.min())]

Division  Stack 
9-10 F    3/3/03    2.13
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw do you know why the name of the `Time` column isn't present both in your code and my original code?

Comment: You're welcome!  When you apply an aggregation function on a single variable, you get a `Series` as output.  It's only one vector, so it doesn't get referenced by name, the way you would in a multi-column data frame.  It's still called `Time`, though, as you can see in the output.  You can also check this with `divstack.name` (you'll see that's equal to `'Time'`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the idxmin function
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html

```
result = df.loc[df.groupby('Competitor').Time.idxmin()]
```

should give you what you want for every competitor. Just filter then for Emma if you need: `result.loc[result.Competitor == 'Emma Slabach']`

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame([['Emma Slabach', '6U F',  '3/3/03', 2.66], ['Emma Slabach', '7-8 F', '3/3/03', 2.41], ['Roger', '6U F', '3/3/03', 3.80]], columns=['Competitor', 'Div
   ...: ision', 'Stack', 'Time'])

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
     Competitor Division   Stack  Time
0  Emma Slabach     6U F  3/3/03  2.66
1  Emma Slabach    7-8 F  3/3/03  2.41
2         Roger     6U F  3/3/03  3.80

In [8]: df.loc[df.groupby('Competitor').Time.idxmin()]
Out[8]: 
     Competitor Division   Stack  Time
1  Emma Slabach    7-8 F  3/3/03  2.41
2         Roger     6U F  3/3/03  3.80
```

Comment: Confused as to how you would filter for Emma though? When I tried `df.loc[df.groupby(['Competitor']=='Emma Slabach').Time.idxmin()]` I'm getting `KeyError: False`

Comment: And there's other columns in the data frame as well, but I specifically need Division, Stack, and Time

Comment: @zainy I just updated my answer: name the groupby result, and then filter result for Emma. Is that more clear ?

Comment: you can groupby only by columns. You can't groupby by expressions (I'm not sure what it would mean). `['Competitor']=='Emma Slabach'` is an expression, not an existing column in the dataframe

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thank you. Just looking into how I'd delete some columns in the output

Comment: then just select the wanted columns like this: `result.loc[result.Competitor == 'Emma Slabach'][['Division', 'Stack', 'Time']]`

Comment: But the good thing about `result` like in my answer is that you fully leverage the groupby, and get the fastest time for every participant, which is really powerful.

Comment: Thanks! Question: I know we're using idxmin and loc, but is it possible to remove the index while using them?